# Using structs for Range variable type

Tags: c#, dictionary, struct, variable-types

I am trying to make a struct for a range variable (minimum, maximum) with a few members and a method to know if between values.

Right now my struct looks like this:

```
public struct NumRange
{
    float maximum;
    float minimum;

    public NumRange(float min, float max) 
    {
        this.maximum = max;
        this.minimum = min;
    }

    public bool IsBetween(float value)
    {
        if (value < maximum && value > minimum)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to make number ranges by

```
NumRange test = new NumRange(15, 20);
```

The whole point of making this range variable type is to make a map key dictionary like:

```
public Dictionary<NumRange, Color> mapKey = new Dictionary<NumRange, Color>();
NumRange test = new NumRange(15, 20);
mapKey.Add(test, Color.Orange);
```

Is this the best way to go about it? Also it doesn't like when I try to add something to mapKey. Says there is invalid tokens such as ',' ')' '('

Comment: Your struct looks fine, though keep in mind that floats may compare in surprising ways.  You'll get better performance with a generic rather than reusing a floating range for integers: `NumRange<T> { T min; T max;...`.

Comment: Follow standard C# capitalization and naming guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx

Comment: @JonofAllTrades How do I use the generic T? Do I replace all instances of float or???

Comment: @Jesse I changed some of it but if you see any other mistakes then please tell me so I do not continue.

Comment: Another possibility is to make the struct immutable, that is, put `readonly` on your members `minimum` and `maximum`. This a) signifies intent: this range is always for these values and b) potentially allows the compiler and/or JITter to optimize things.

Comment: @MLM: If you're not at all familiar with generics, then it's probably better to stick to hard-coded `float` or `int` for now.  But read up on generics some time, they're very handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a finite number of values to look up, a dictionary may not be the best choice.  It looks like you're mapping ranges of values to colors to apply to a height map.  This stub of a class will let you do so, but note that it does not accommodate blending from color A to color B.

```cs
class RangeMap<T>
{
    private SortedList<float, T>  _values;

    public RangeMap()
    {
        _values = new SortedList<float, T>();
    }

    public void AddPoint(float max, T value)
    {
        _values[max] = value;
    }

    public T GetValue(float point)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(point)) return _values[point];

        return (from kvp in _values where kvp.Key > point select kvp.Value)
               .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

```cs
var  map = new RangeMap<Color>();
map.AddPoint(0.0F, Color.Red);
map.AddPoint(0.5F, Color.Green);
map.AddPoint(1.0F, Color.Blue);

Console.WriteLine(map.GetValue(-0.25F).Name);
Console.WriteLine(map.GetValue( 0.25F).Name);
Console.WriteLine(map.GetValue( 0.75F).Name);
Console.WriteLine(map.GetValue( 1.25F).Name);
```

Output: Red, Green, Blue, empty struct.

Comment: @FredrikSundmyhr: It's rude to change someone's code just to conform to your personal style (bracket indentation).  Kindly save your time for material changes.  See Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133224/is-it-rude-to-change-someones-brackets-style.

Comment: Your code was unnecessarily indented four extra spaces.  Happens all the time, so removing the indent is a common edit and is definitely worthwhile.  As is ensuring all the code is visible without having to scroll horizontally or vertically.

Comment: @Will: That would be a worthwhile change.  However, per the edit history, his change was just to change brace style from Whitesmiths to Allman, and moving the prop to before the constructor: a waste of time at best, and an invitation to religious war.

Comment: Hah!  Oh, I didn't even notice that.  Just looks like badly indented code to me.  Which is a common occurrence.  Didn't consider it a style.  Oh well.  Anyhow, there's no need for a religious war when the bible (framework design guidelines) is pretty clear on the subject.